# Ext.Ajax.request how to set response headers in a get operation

Tags: javascript, firefox, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

i'm using extjs 4.1 and i want to get a file from an url and download to the correct position.
All I want to do is to set the response header.

Iwould like to set the "content-type" to a different value (for example "application/force-download"). It's for me necessary otherwise firefox don't save the file to the download directory!

this is my sample code. Where is the mistake/where have I to add the information to the response headers?

```
var certurl = 'http://' + myurl +'/myfile.groovy';
Ext.Ajax.request({
            method : 'GET',
            url : 'http://' + myurl +'/myfile.groovy', //this file exixst!!!
            success : function(response, opts) {
                var link = document.createElement("a");
                var fileName = 'myfile.groovy'
                link.download = fileName;
                link.href = certurl;
                link.click();
},
            failure : function(response, opts) {}
                            });
```

Comment: Where do you set response headers? In the server. The only headers you can manipulate from the client are the request's ones.

Comment: For what I can understand from your code you are creating a link and "clicking" in an attempt to trigger the file download. Are you trying to trigger the file download using the Ajax request?

Comment: yes  overlordhammer, correct! @rixo I don't set actually response header. I think (is it true??) that the framework set them for me, but defeult headers is not good for me. And I'm using ajax only to make a link and click it programmatically; the file is in a known location in the tomcat directory, so I don't know where to set the headers....

Comment: I think you should only use `document.location = 'http://' + myurl +'/myfile.groovy'`

Comment: @Alexey Solonets I've tried... this cause only the browser redirect, and the file is opened into the browser, not "downloaded"

Comment: This is browser behavior, you cannot change it. The only way for you is to change the 'Content-Type' on server.